# Issue storing arrays in SQLite using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sqlite, cordova

I've been using Cordova and the storage adapter for SQLite. When I store objects using `JSON.stringify` and the retrieve them they work. I also have several fields that are arrays, but when I store them they are just stored comma-delimited. If there is only one item in the array then it's just stored as a single string.

Initial Array:

```
["test1", "test2", "test3"]
```

Stored As:

```
test1, test2, test3
```

I could just split those specific fields when I retrieve them from the database, but still wondering if there is a better way to store them. Is there a elegant way to store an array and retrieve it in SQLite using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem ,you can access initial array after parsing (JSON.parse(yourStringifiedArrayString)).

```
  var yourarr=["test1", "test2", "test3"];
  var afterStringify = JSON.stringify(yourarr);
  console.log('After Stringify:'+afterStringify);
  var prevArr=JSON.parse(afterStringify);
  console.log('After Parsing:'+prevArr);
  //now access your array
   alert(prevArr[1]);//will show test2
```

[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nrg2a/)

Comment: I guess you're right. It looks stringifying and parsing arrays works too, even if they aren't JSON. I'd imagine using split would be less expensive on the processor though?

Comment: I don't think split would be less expensive. if you are agree with my answer then you should accept it.

Comment: I just switched all of my splits to use the json functions and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with saving an array as a delimited string - It works fine for me. Just need to recreate the array using split() method when you retrieve it from SQLite.

Comment: Yes, I know it's something I can work around, though I have a lot of tables and fields. It just feels like a lot of extra logic to check for those fields and then split them before returning the results.